# Swagger documentation not available when subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, ruby-grape

Using the `grape-swagger` gem, I've setted a subdomain on Grape Swagger as such in `routes.rb`

```
constraints subdomain: /api/ do
  mount Api::V1::Base => '/'
end
```

And here is document.rb

```
require 'grape-swagger'

module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    mount API::Cats

    add_swagger_documentation
  end
end
```

However, when I go to `http://api.localhost:3000/swagger_doc` , I get a routing error

> No route matches [GET] "/swagger_doc"

If I remove the constraints, I can access to `http://localhost:3000/swagger_doc` .

I tried to add a `base_path` parameter to `add_swagger_documentation` but to no avail.

Any hint on what I might have done wrong ?